# Filling the rows of a matrix with vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suppose that i am using a function 'fun' that computes a 3-dimensional vector. What i want is to create, using a for loop, a matrix having the vectors 'fun' computes each time as its rows.

thanks,
Nikos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how many times are you going to be running the function 'fun'? Let's call that 'n'.

```
% if you know the number of times you are going to run 'fun' you can initialize the final 
matrix to be output = zeros(n,3);

n = 5;

output = zeros(n,3);

for i=1:n
    output(i,:) = fun(); % and you have to give whatever parameters 'fun' takes here
end
```

I'm not sure if that totally answers your question but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: the major concern that I have with your question is that, for you to create this using a for loop, you would need to be able to change the inputs to 'fun' inside of the loop.  There are a number of ways you can do this. If you give a more concrete example of what you want, I can help more.  You can also still run the above code even if you don't know the number of times you are going to run 'fun'.  Essentially, I gave a very generic answer to your generic question, if you have more specifics, I or someone else can help more.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) the only input to 'fun' required is the 'i' of the for loop. To be more specific i want each time to read a different .tif image and they go like: s1_1.TIF, s1_2.TIF etc. By the way how can i state inside the body of 'f' something like F=imread('s3_i.TIF')?

Comment: @nikos, you can say something like 

`for i=1:n
    filename = ['s1_' num2str(i) '.tif'];
    F = imread(filename);
end`

Comment: and if i want to name a variable that way, e.g. i have a for loop that goes: for i=1:5 and i want a variable named m1, m2,...,m5 how am i gonna state it?

Comment: again its going to depend on exactly what you are storing as to what is the best method to use.  if 'm' is just a number value each time  you can just store it in a matrix(/vector).  just say m[i] = its respective value at each iteration. you can use a similar method for storing vectors and matrices of the same size at each iteration,  however, if you are trying to store items of varying size you are going to have to use a cell array which uses the notation m{i} = the respective value. does that make sense?

Comment: @nikos, i'd be happy to keep helping you if you have more questions, but since I am new to this site it would be rather exciting for me if you would accept my answer if you think I did actually answer your question.  in any case, i would still be happy to make any of my answers more clear if you are still having troubles!